# Create db Synonyms that include login credentials

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'd like to create a synonym on a local db that points to a db on the web that's only accessible with a user name and password. Is there a way to set up a synonym for that kind of situation?

I would be very grateful for an example if this is even possible...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You simply permission a synonym the same way as you'd permission any object

```
  GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.SynonymForSomething TO RoleWithThisOneUser
```

Saying that, you can't use synonyms for linked servers if that's what you want...